# Reporting across project repositories

Tags: git, tfs, repository, reporting

Given many projects in our enterprise Azure Devops subscription, is there a way for me to "report" on the types of repositories in each? Like if we have 60 projects, can I get a report that tells me the type of repo sitting in each one?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the "type" of a repository?

Comment: Whether they are GIT or not.

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation? Querying projects and repositories is fully supported by the APIs.

Comment: I was hoping for a less code centric way to get at that. Just a "report".

Answer (score -1):

> is there a way for me to "report" on the types of repositories in each?

I am afraid there is no such a way to achieve this at this moment.

We could use the REST API [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to get all the all git type repos:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0
```

But this above REST API couold not get the TFVC repo, and there is no such REST API to get it.

We could use the develop tool F12 to get the REST API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_versionControl?__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to get a complete list of projects? I am thinking that if I had the overall list, then I knew which ones were using GIT, that would be what I am looking for.